# Delay in updating referenced cells when using IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I'm using the IMPORTRANGE function in Google Sheets to reference data from `spreadsheet1` and display it in `spreadsheet2`. This works fine, but if I edit `spreadsheet1` and then go to `spreadsheet2` it's not automatically updated, nor does it update if I refresh the page. I've set my cache to be limited to 0MB so it shouldn't be saving anything locally.

Any ideas how I can get it to check back to the master spreadsheet more often and update its values accordingly?

Comment: Read the following URL: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BsOdrVdZYdI

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Instead of using `IMPORTRANGE` use [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/)

## Explanation

According to [Change a spreadsheet's locale, time zone, recalculation, and language](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en) the recalculation interval for `IMPORTRANGE` is 30 mins. If shorter recalculation interval is needed then somehow the formula parameters should be changed.

Unfortunately, in the new Google Sheets is not possible to use `NOW`, `RAND` or `RANDBETWEEN` functions, so the alternative is to use a Google Apps Script.

## Explanation about the use of non-deterministic functions

In the thread provided in the [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43116/delay-in-updating-referenced-cells-when-using-importrange-in-google-sheets#comment34139_43116) by Jacob Jan Tuinstra it's mentioned the use of an extra URL parameter that it's updated at certain intervals. That thread is from 2011.

The core idea was to add to the URL something like  `"&workaround="&NOW()` and set the recalculation setting to `on change and every minute` but this could be too frequent as the import task could take more than one minute, so instead of `NOW()` you should round it to a good enough interval, let's say 10 minutes, then instead of `NOW()` use

```
INT(NOW()/TIME(0;10;0))
```

Let name this formulas `time_interval`.

The cell formula containing `IMPORTRANGE` will look like this

```
=IMPORTRANGE(
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spredsheet_key&workaround="&time_interval,
  "Sheet1!A1:AB"
 )
```

Unfortunately the above formula returns the following error

> Error
>   This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(),
>   RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN()

The same happens with the other import functions (`IMPORTDATA`, `IMPORTHTML`, `IMPORTFEED`, `IMPORTXML`)

## References

- [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)